# Codeigniter redirect doubles URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, controller

I'm using codeigniter in localhost and I'm trying to redirect my controller to another controller, so what I basically do is:

```
        redirect('/account/index');
```

However, it does not go to the URL, instead it goes here:

```
http://localhost/ticketsystem/index.php/logincheck/localhost/ticketsystem/index.php/account/index
```

It doubles my address. Do I need to set something in my config.php? My setup in my config.php is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/ticketsystem';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Do I need to change something there, or am I doing something else that makes my redirect cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your base url should be looks like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ticketsystem/';
```

use redirect like :-

```
redirect('account/index', 'refresh');
```

refresh will use meta refresh and should quick redirect

Answer (score 3):

The `base_url` behaving like relative path, change into complete url, and also add `'/'` in last

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/ticketsystem';
```

To

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ticketsystem/';
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the '/' before account!

```
redirect('account/index');
```